# FPDF MakeFont does not generate any file

Tags: php, pdf-generation, fpdf

I would like to add font with local signs to the FPDF but it doesn't work.
Acording the [tutorial](http://www.fpdf.org/) I have written:

```
require('../makefont/makefont.php');
MakeFont('c:\\Windows\\Fonts\\verdana.TTF','cp1252', true);
```

It produces the message:
Font file compressed: verdana.z
Font definition file generated: verdana.php

In the fpdf tut I read "Then copy the generated files to the font directory."
But I have not that files on my disc. What is wrong with it? Where are they?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

From memory, I haven't used FPDF font generator for a long time, I believe that you need to copy your ttf font file out of the c:\windows\Fonts.

I think it has something do to with permissions on the c:\windows\Fonts, and the generated fonts should be on the folder you are running that php script, so if you are running the fontgenerator.php from say: c:\www\font_generator.php, the fonts definitions files should be on c:\www\verdana.z

Comment: Thanks, meanwhile I solve it by mPDF. But today I try FPDF againg and it works fine.